# Node JS serving HTML pages Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a multiplayer game where a server connects two clients to play against each other. It works well. However, now I want to add a welcome page where they add their username. I need to send this username to the server. However, the problem is, when loading the welcome page it makes a connection to the server (which is good). But, when i want to load the next page using

```
location.href = "index.html"
```

it is not working. In fact, it disconnects from the server and does not reconnect. How do I load multiple files after a player hits a button? And how do I keep these files under the same "client" instance? (without disconnecting). Thank you.

Comment: please show code

Comment: I actually wrote out the question here too haha:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428057/nodejs-rooms-not-working-after-redirect
I did not realize at that point tho that it was not working because the page was disconnecting from the server at the location.href point

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no code, let me take a stab at it. To expand on what @anderson said, Make sure you have your static files available to your app via something like

```
const staticCont = express.static(__dirname + "/public");
```

Where "public" is, is the folder directory of all your static files. This way, any link in your app(on the front end) that requires loading of whatever files, will be available to you.

Next, assuming this was done, also, assuming your game is on a singular page, lets say `"mygame.html`", if you want to load another html or other content into this page without losing/navigating away from "`mygame.html`", then on the users button press you are going to need AJAX to load in content.

as an example:

Create  a dummy div that will hold your loaded content, lets call it

```
<div id="usrBioWrapper"></div>
```

Then say you have a button on your app that fetches a users bio.
Lets call this button
`<button id="usrBio">Get user bio</button>`

and the html you want to load is called `usrBioPage.html`, then you'd need something like:

```
$('#usrBio').on('click', function(){
    $('#usrBioWrapper').load(' usrBioPage.html ');
});
```

Thats it. When the user clicks the button, it will load your content in that div. BUT remember, you must set the public directory in your app.js(backend node side) else it wont work.

hope this helps

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution thank you. I also found it worked if I simply make the welcome file disconnected from the server and then stored the username is sessionstorage in the browser and retrieved the information that way.

Answer (score -1):

Did you public your `index.html` file in Node js, to make sure your browser can access the file?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. To simplify my question, how do I load another html page, without disconnecting from the server?